# Proving the statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In the case, if the statement is true, prove it, if false, give a counterexample.

$$\forall a,b \in \mathbb N^+, 3| (a^2+b^2) \implies 3 |a \land 3|b$$

How do I prove this?

Comment: If $3\nmid a,3\nmid b$, then $a$ and $b$ are of the form ???? and ???? and $a^2+b^2=????$...

Answer (score 2):

If $3\nmid a$, then $a^2 \equiv 1\pmod 3$, and $b^2 \equiv 0\pmod 3$ or $b^2 \equiv 1\pmod 3$. So $a^2 + b^2 \equiv 1\pmod 3$ or $a^2 + b^2 \equiv 2\pmod 3$, contradiction. The case that $3\nmid b$ is done similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Prove the contrapositive: Assume $3$ does not divide $a$ or $b$, and compute $a^2 + b^2 \mod 3$. Then assume $3$ divides one of $a$ or $b$, and similarly compute $a^2 + b^2 \mod 3$